# How to add a prefix to a Iterator item?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to convert a binary string to a character but each string is stored in a Iterator so I can not add a *`b`* infront of them. How can I change my code to make this happen?

```
originalText = "This is a message!"
text2Binary = [format(ord(x), 'b') for x in originalText]

textLength = len(originalText)
text2BinaryList = iter(text2Binary)
binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)

for i in range(textLength):
    print(binary2TextCycler)
```

Comment: Please, add [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You mean something like `print("b{}".format(binary2TextCycler))`? It is not perfectly clear what you expect. Could you add your expected output?

Comment: Yea. Thank you @newbie. I'm new to python so I didn't knew I could simply do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you're missing how iteration works.

```
originalText = "This is a message!"
text2Binary = [format(ord(x), 'b') for x in originalText]
```

Now you have a list—which is already an iterable—of the binary strings representing each character. And I think that's all you wanted. You can just iterate them to print them out:

```
for binary in text2Binary:
    print(binary)
```

---

If you want to change the format they get printed in, just change the format string you pass to `format` in the original comprehension:

```
text2Binary = [format(ord(x), '#010b') for x in originalText]
```

The `#` means "alternate format", the `0` means fill with 0s, an the `10` means fill to 10 characters, so what you get is:

```
0b01010100
0b01101000
0b01101001
0b01110011
… etc.
```

If you want a different format, just use a different format spec. To add extra characters, you might want to use `str.format` instead of just `format`:

```
text2Binary = ['b{:b}'.format(ord(x)) for x in originalText]
```

… or an f-string:

```
text2Binary = [f'b{ord(x):b}' for x in originalText]
```

---

Now, let's look at all the extra stuff you added:

```
textLength = len(originalText)
# ...
for i in range(textLength):
```

While this *could* work, you don't *need* the length of something to iterate over it; just iterate over it directly.

Meanwhile:

```
text2BinaryList = iter(text2Binary)
binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)
```

This creates an iterator over your list, and then gets the first element out of that iterator. So, `binary2TextCycler` is just going to be the string `'0b01010100'`. It doesn't matter how many times you loop over some other iterable, like `range(textLength)`, you've still got the same first string each time.

As a side note: `text2Binary` is a list, and `text2BinaryList` is an iterator over that list. That's pretty confusing naming, and it may be why you confused yourself.

Anyway, if you wanted to make this work, you would have to advance the iterator again and store the new value each time through the loop:

```
for i in range(textLength):
    print(binary2TextCycler)
    binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)
```

But if you understand how `for` loops work, this is equivalent to:

```
text2BinaryList = iter(text2Binary)
binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)
textLengthIterator = iter(range(textLength))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(textLengthIterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(binary2TextCycler)
    binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)
```

You can obviously remove the extra `next`:

```
text2BinaryList = iter(text2Binary)
textLengthIterator = iter(range(textLength))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(textLengthIterator)
        binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(binary2TextCycler)
```

So, it should be obvious that you can replace that by just looping over a `zip` of the two iterables:

```
for i, binary2TextCycler in zip(range(textLength), text2BinaryList):
    print(binary2TextCycler)
```

And then, you don't need the `iter`; you can just use the iterable directly:

```
for i, binary2TextCycler in zip(range(textLength), text2Binary):
    print(binary2TextCycler)
```

And, since you're not actually using `i` for anything, and the two iterables are the same length, you can just drop the first one entirely:

```
for binary2TextCycler in text2BinaryList:
    print(binary2TextCycler)
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
originalText = "This is a message!"
text2Binary = [format(ord(x), 'b') for x in originalText]

textLength = len(originalText)
text2BinaryList = iter(text2Binary)
binary2TextCycler = next(text2BinaryList)

for i in range(textLength):
    print('b%s' %(binary2TextCycler))
```

returns

> b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100
>   b1010100...